# How do I use a Java or Scala http client with a link-local ipv6 address?

Tags: java, linux, scala, networking

What is the best Java or Scala client for issuing link-local http requests? Also, what's an example of how to use the client with link-local addresses (this is fairly complicated and error prone for unix utilities such as curl, which often don't even work with link-local addresses at all due to the requirement of including the interface in the address). I'm looking for a solution that works on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

All Java HTTP client libraries make use of Java's lower level network address and socket libraries.  These "just work" with IPv6 ... assuming that your operating system and network have IPv6 networking configured properly.

**UPDATE** - Java supports IPv6 "zone identifiers" aka "scoped addresses" in Java 6 onwards.  Refer to the javadocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html#scoped) for the details.

So, basically, you should be able to use a Java HTTP client library with IPv6 link-local addresses the same way you use it with other kinds of addresses.

Additional reference:

- http://veithen.github.io/2013/12/30/how-to-correctly-parse-ipv6-addresses.html

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between link-local addresses and ipv6 addresses in general. You need to specify the network interface to use. If you're truly using a non-routed link-local address (i.e., one that is only available across switches in a subdomain), then "ping6 [fe80...etc etc]" will not work. This is definitely not an issue with an ISP or the networking configuration. Curl has a bug in it's handling of link-local addresses due to malformatting of the Host header. Manually typing the http request into telnet works fine.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6) the difference is that each NIC has a distinct link-local address.  Obviously that a host with multiple NICs has multiple link-local addresses, and that may present a problem if you are referring to a host by name and an DNS lookup gives you the IPv6 for a NIC that you can't talk / route to.  Ditto if you try to ping an IPv6 link-local address you can't route to.  Using a Java client won't help with this.

Comment: As for bugs in curl.  1) Try wget instead.  2) The latest version of curl apparently handles IPv6 zone identifiers ... which I think is the thing that was tripping you up.  See http://www.geekssharingspace.org/2014/05/curl-7370-released-with-ipv6-zone.html.  Also, see the curl issue tracker at http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/ for activity on recent IPv6 related issues.

Comment: Normal DNS and DHCP are not in the picture; they are switched off for these nodes. There are no routes being advertised by any means other than multicast-DNS (Bonjour/Avahi). Because the addresses are discovered via these tools, they are reachable by that interface (again, per my comment, I can send an HTTP request to the target server using telnet with an address something like: `[fe80...]%eth0`). Looking up by hostname should work in these cases (since mDNS can be included in resolution for `.local` hostnames), but unfortunately on linux there is a known bug in GLIB that prevents this.